# Breeze Batch Saves for some entities

Tags: breeze

We use the Abstract Dataservice REST Adapter in Breeze, but are interested in batching saves for some entities.  We depend on synchronous saves, so we want certain entities to be posted down together.  Is this something we need to write custom adapter code to accomplish, or is there any options that Breeze has available out of the box?  Any insight on similar patterns would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a custom adapter would be necessary, it sounds like you might be able to use [EntityManager.getChanges](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_getChanges), specifying the entity type:

```
var custType = em.metadataStore.getEntityType("Customer");
var changedCustomers = em.getChanges(custType);
em.saveChanges(changedCustomers);
```

You will want to update the code to reflect your business rules, but you should find getChanges helpful.